# Raycasting from one object to another

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to cast a ray from one object to another but it is not working properly.

Result:

[image]

Selected object is "EnemyTank" and ray should point to "PlayerTank" but it is not as you can see.

My code:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 dir = player.transform.position - rayOrigin.transform.position;
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        dir = dir.normalized;
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin.transform.position, dir*maxCheckDistance,Color.red);
}
```

`player` variable points to "PlayerTank"

Playertank location:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of maxCheckDistance?

Comment: Write those 2 comments as the answer.

Comment: Why the `rayOrigin` though? Just use `transform.position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few issues that I can see, but straight to the point:

`FixedUpdate` Runs on a set interval, it isn't every frame.  the Method `DrawRay()`  Has a parameter for duration.  by default it is set to 0.  This means it will only be visible for a single frame.  You have 2 choices you can pass in a duration, or you can put this method in `update` which does run every frame.

```
void Update () {
        Vector3 dir = player.transform.position - rayOrigin.transform.position;
        dir = dir.normalized;
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin.transform.position, dir*maxCheckDistance,Color.red);
}
```

However if you are trying to draw a line from one object to another just use `Debug.DrawLine()`

```
Debug.DrawLine(rayOrigin.transform.position, player.transform.position, Color.red);
```

Lastly, avoid using a color for your line that is the same as one of your objects, I am referring to your red cube, and red line.  Use a color that will stand out.  Say black in this case.

**FixedUpdate example:**

```
void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 dir = player.transform.position - rayOrigin.transform.position;
        dir = dir.normalized;
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin.transform.position, dir*maxCheckDistance,Color.red, 1.0f);
}
```

For fun, to have the line change colors using your maxCheckDistance value:

```
void Update () {
    Color lineColor = color.Black;
    if(Vector3.Distance(rayOrigin.transform.position, player.transform.position) < maxCheckDistance) {
        lineColor = color.White;
    }
    Debug.DrawLine(rayOrigin.transform.position, player.transform.position, lineColor);
}
```

**EDIT:**

It is important to know where your objects actually are, in your question you have a Player object, that you made the parent of 2 cubes.  It appears as though you moved those 2 cubes into where you wanted the player to be in the world instead of moving the Player object itself.  So your line is drawing correctly, as it is getting the position to the player object, In the future move the parent object instead of the children object.

Comment: @TolgayToklar where is "Ray" Origin? and how are you getting the player?

Comment: This is ray origin: http://prntscr.com/jhpyk0 and this is the player: http://prntscr.com/jhpz9v (I am sure tag is correct.)

Comment: Make the player transform public in your script, and check to see where it is located.  This will verify whether you are getting the correct player object(helps eliminate whether you have multiple objects with the player tag), and if the ray is going to the correct location based off of the information provided.

Comment: I made it public but nothing changed still same http://prntscr.com/jhqbm0

Comment: Tolgay, where is your PlayerTanks Transform located(Not the location of its children)  I notice your Collider has a weird offset, ~2.5 units above, ~1.5 units to the left and ~2.6 units in front.

Comment: In unity make a sphere, as a child of your PlayerTank, set that spheres position to 0,0,0 in the inspector.  This is the easiest way I can think of how to explain where your PlayerTank transform really is.  Remove the colliders from it and then see if the line goes to the center of that sphere.  (Make sure you make it a child of the PlayerTank)

Comment: Alright, your screenshot shows us that your tank is not where you think it is.  I would set your colliders offset to 0 again, and then move the "Body"/"turret" of your tank to be based off of where that sphere is (As that is the actual location of your tank transform and those components you positioned in world space instead of where they would be in local space).

Answer (score 0):

From your description and screenshot.

You want to draw ray from "EnemyTank" to "PlayerTank".

and in your code "PlayerTank" is `player` and "EnemyTank" is `rayOrigin`.

There has draw a small ray from "EnemyTank" to some other direction. So you definitely miss to define your "PlayerTank" in `player` object.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The **direction** parameter in **DrawRay** is a vector in global space.
Thus your ray always points more or less to the origin.</strike>

Sorry, my answer is wrong.

Comment: Not true,  If you set a start position, and provide a "direction", then there is no reason for the ray to point at the origin(being worldspace 0,0,0).  Infact, if that was the case then there would be no use for a direction parameter if you gave a position.

Comment: Look at the the unity-docs example code: Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green); Obvious in global space.

Comment: I am looking at the unity docs, notice in the example code they provide the collision point for the start and the collision normal?  If it always pointed at origin then that normal would be useless.

Comment: With the code you provided, it says draw a ray from my position(Which can be anywhere in the world), to a point 10 units in front of me, that is not pointing at origin.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but than I am confused what the 'TransformDirection' (converts to global space) is good for. I'll test it at home

Comment: 'in front of me' yes, but not in local coords.

Comment: TransformDirection converts a local space direction to a world space direction.   Vector3.forward is literally (0,0,1) if you used `TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)` you will get the same results as transform.forward.  transform.forward is the forward direction already in world spaced where Vector3.forward is a forward vector in a localspace.

Comment: Jockel1x3 `(target.position - player.position).normalized` is a world direction.

Comment: If you take the code from the documentation you quoted, and changed it to `Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward*10, Color.green)` you will get the same results.